# Retaining those replicates of a function which do not produce error

Tags: r, statistics

Suppose I have a function which return result without any error when the sample size is large. When n is small, for few particular datasets, the function produces error and I just want to exclude those replicates entirely and work with the other replicates which don't have any issue. But once any replicate produce error,  all other replicates that execute become unusable. For example, consider the toy example below:

```
sim <- function(n){

x <- rbinom(n,1,0.3)
a <- x[1:(n/2)]
b <- x[((n/2)+1):n]
d <- c(table(a)[[1]],table(a)[[2]],table(b)[[1]],table(b)[[2]])
return(d)

}

 set.seed(5)
 ans1 <-replicate(100,sim(100))
 ans2 <- replicate(100,sim(30))#Error in table(b)[[2]] : subscript out of bounds
```

In this example, I want to retain those replicates of ans2 which have all the four cells `c(table(a)[[1]],table(a)[[2]],table(b)[[1]],table(b)[[2]])`. And remove those replicates which produce the error. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `try` and then remove anything with class `try-error`:

```
sim <- function(n){
  try({
    x <- rbinom(n,1,0.3)
    a <- x[1:(n/2)]
    b <- x[((n/2)+1):n]
    d <- c(table(a)[[1]],table(a)[[2]],table(b)[[1]],table(b)[[2]])
    return(d)
  }, silent = TRUE)
}

set.seed(5)
ans2 <- replicate(100,sim(30))

indx <- vapply(ans2, class, NA_character_) != "try-error"
ans2 <- ans2[indx]
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are trying split the vector into 2 and count the number of 0s and 1s. One solution is to first create another vector that splits you 0s and 1s into 2:

```
x = c(rep(0,5),c(1,1,1,0,0))
a_or_b <- 1:10 > 10/2
```

We can see the above splits the 0s and 1s:

```
cbind(x,a_or_b)

      x a_or_b
 [1,] 0      0
 [2,] 0      0
 [3,] 0      0
 [4,] 0      0
 [5,] 0      0
 [6,] 1      1
 [7,] 1      1
 [8,] 1      1
 [9,] 0      1
[10,] 0      1
```

Now we use table:

```
table(x,a_or_b)

   a_or_b
x   FALSE TRUE
  0     5    2
  1     0    3
```

Now we write this as a function:

```
sim <- function(n){

x <- rbinom(n,1,0.3)
a_or_b <- 1:n > n/2
return(c(table(x,a_or_b)))
}

replicate(100,sim(30))
#no error
```